# How to mock a class called later than the method you are testing?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing the unit test of a method x of class A, but this method, among other things, creates an instance of a class B that uses a service C which is normally executed by an Application server. The problem is to create a mock of the C service even if this is not explicitly instantiated and called by the method x of the class A of which I am making the unitTest

I would not want to create confusion, since we are inside a J2EE code that requires knowledge of the whole architecture to be explained, so I formulated the question in a very generic way.
However I am attaching a part of class B (called inside the method for which I am writing the unit test), in particular what is necessary to show how class C is instantiated (which I would like to somehow mock since the test must work without the Application server).

```
public class MarketResponseProcessorImpl implements MarketResponseProcessor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MarketResponseProcessorImpl.class);
    private static final String LOG_MARKET_ATTRIBUTE_REQUEST_NOT_VALID = " - marketAttributeRequest not valid";

    private EventResponse eventResponse;

    private BOClientServiceManager service;

    private BobaRequestType requestType;

    public MarketResponseProcessorImpl(EventResponse eventResponse, BobaRequestType requestType) {
        this.eventResponse = eventResponse;
        this.requestType = requestType;
        this.service = BOClientServiceManager.getInstance();
    }
```

Class C in this example is

```
BOClientServiceManager service
```

Comment: How does class B use service C? Does it get an instance of C passed to it? Can you show some code?

Comment: I have integrated with a part of the code that shows how B instantiates C

Comment: Can you change the code in the constructor to inject `service` instead of calling `BOClientServiceManager.getInstance()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [mock a static method using Mockito](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks) from version 3.4 upwards:

```
  try (MockedStatic<BOClientServiceManager> mockService = Mockito.mockStatic(BOClientServiceManager.class)) {
      mockService.when(BOClientServiceManager::getInstance)
              .thenReturn(mockService);
      // Here you can test your class that creates a MarketResponseProcessorImpl...
    }
```